# Зачем windows позволяет создавать приватные кучи?

Tags: winapi, memory, memory-management

Каждый процесс в ОС Windows имеет по умолчанию свою кучу, размер которой в будущем может быть изменен. Более того, каждый процесс способен так же создавать кучу с определенным, наперед заданным начальным и максимальным размером (такая куча будет называться приватной). Зачем такая возможность существует в Windows? Чтобы оптимизировать реаллокации? Но тогда не достаточно ли в таком случае использования обычной кучи по умолчанию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При создании кучи можно задавать наличие следующих параметров:

- `HEAP_CREATE_ENABLE_EXECUTE` — разместить кучу на страницах с правом на исполнение. Подобное можно использовать для JIT-компиляции небольших фрагментов кода, когда выделение целой 4КБ страницы на фрагмент было бы излишним.
- `HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS` — выбрасывать SEH-исключения из функций управления кучей.
- `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE` — разменять поддержку многоточности на скорость выделения/высвобождения блоков кучи.

В куче по умолчанию ничего из вышеперечисленного не включено.

Comment: Отличное замечание